# HTTP post request keeps sending an empty body

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am sending a post request to my server and from the server side, I only get an empty body.

My client is with angular.

Here is the code for the service that sends the request:

```
public constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public addImagePair(gameName: string, originalImage: File, modifiedImage: File): Observable<ICommonImagePair> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", gameName);
    formData.append("originalImage", originalImage);
    formData.append("modifiedImage", modifiedImage);

    new Response(formData).text().then(console.log);
    return this.http.post<ICommonImagePair>(this.BASE_URL + "image-pair", formData);
  }

  public addGameCard(gameName: string, imagePairId: string, pov: POVType): Observable<ICommonGameCard> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", gameName);
    formData.append("image-pair-id", imagePairId);
    formData.append("pov", "Simple");

    new Response(formData).text().then(console.log);
    return this.http.post<ICommonGameCard>(this.BASE_URL + "gamecard", formData);
  }
```

Here is the code for the component that calls the service:

```
public addImagePair(): void {
    this.simplePOVGameGeneratorService.addImagePair(this.gameName, this.originalImageFile, this.modifiedImageFile)
      .subscribe((imagePair: ICommonImagePair) => {
        this.simplePOVGameGeneratorService.addGameCard(imagePair.name, imagePair.id, POVType.Simple)
          .subscribe((gameCard: ICommonGameCard) => {
            console.log(gameCard);
          });
      });
  }
```

In my component, I first make a request for `addImagePair()`, which does send a request without any issues. Then, I call `addGameCard()` with almost the same code and somehow the body is empty. I console log before making the request to make sure there is actually data. I also console log on the server and the body is empty. What the hell could cause this?

Comment: Why are you using `new Response(formData).text().then(console.log);` , try to remove this line and use `return this.http.post<ICommonImagePair>(this.BASE_URL + "image-pair", JSON.stringify(formData));`

Comment: @Niladri Thanks for the reply. I am using that first line because I want to print what I am sending from the client to make sure it's not empty, which is not. I also tried adding JSON.stringify() and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try to use `console.log(imagePair)` in the first subscribe of `subscribe((imagePair: ICommonImagePair) => {`

Comment: @Niladri Yes, it returned the object as expected. After doing some digging, it seems that FormData could have issues with strings. Is it possible that appending strings in form data could mess it up?

Comment: That might be an issue .. try to use it like this .. formdata = `{ "name":gameName,"image-pair-id":imagePairId,"pov": "Simple"}` and then use `return this.http.post<ICommonImagePair>(this.BASE_URL + "image-pair", JSON.stringify(formData));`

Comment: it's better to use `flatMap` operator from rxjs in this case to chain the nested observables.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flatMap` operator instead of manually subscribing to nested observables like below -

```
public addImagePair(): void {
    this.simplePOVGameGeneratorService.addImagePair(this.gameName, this.originalImageFile, this.modifiedImageFile)
      .flatMap((imagePair: ICommonImagePair) => this.simplePOVGameGeneratorService.addGameCard(imagePair.name, imagePair.id, POVType.Simple))
       .subscribe((gameCard: ICommonGameCard) => {
            console.log(gameCard);
          });
      });
  }
```

You can also pass the data in the post method as string literal instead of `FormData` like formdata = `{ "name":gameName,"image-pair-id":imagePairId,"pov": "Simple"}` and then use `return this.http.post<ICommonImagePair>(this.BASE_URL + "image-pair", JSON.stringify(formData));` in the `addGameCard` method.